# Did the WB-app “hat engine” break down during the 1st of January 2022?

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

When trying to see changes in the Winter Bash (WB) Network-wide leaderboard, I found no changes during several hours. No hats attributed at all. What was the reason for this bug?

I should have received the “I voted” hat on *[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)* (voted at: 03:06 PM UTC) and on *[Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tour)* (voted at: 07:51 PM UTC).

Then I found out that the leaderboard doesn’t update and was following its output

> 737,171 users from around the network have earned a total of 902,906
> hats!
>
> Checked at     08:25 PM UTC Again  at    09:06 PM UTC
>
> 737,169 users from around the network have earned a total of 902,902
> hats! Checked at     22:49 PM UTC    looks like 2 user were removed (incl. 4
> hats)
>
> 737,167 users from around the network have earned a total of 902,898
> hats! Checked at     23:57 PM UTC    looks like 2 user were removed (incl. 4
> hats)
>
> 737,164 users from around the network have earned a total of 902,895
> hats! Checked at     01:09 AM UTC    looks like 3 user were removed (incl. 3
> hats)
>
> 737,163 users from around the network have earned a total of 902,894 hats! Checked at     01:44AM UTC    looks like 1 user were removed (incl. 1
> hats)
>
> 737,162 users from around the network have earned a total of 902,893 hats! Checked at 02:55AM UTC looks like 1 user were removed (incl. 1 hats)

Does this mean eventually triggered hats got lost? Did WB stop due last year's 2nd of January end date (not updated)? Are hats which should have been earned recoverable?

Comment: I asked my first questions during WB on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70550089/17242583) and [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/240421/110034), both were positively received, I commented several times, and on CG it was my first post, and yet I got ZERO hats...

Comment: I also didn't get I voted(after testing). How did you get the data?

Comment: @Wolgwang On the Network Wide leaderboard

Comment: Weirdly, the number of hats went up by about 20 since the last edit... Not really what I would expect as making up for the time it wasn't doing anything. It's more likely that the process is either timing out or otherwise failing for some reason.

Comment: @animuson Realized that too, but now it needs to be fixed, since New Moon's could be awarded already.

Comment: [Fixed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60034212#60034212) by Yaakov Ellis.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, the hat awards were hung for about 12 hours network-wide. I have run it manually a few times, trying to figure out some timeout issues with it (but limited with how much I can fix over the weekend).

Comment: thank you for fixing it on a Sunday !